# jQuery this selector in the object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(".paketler").hover(function() {
  $(".paketfav").addClass("paketfavhover");
}, function() {
  $(".paketfav").removeClass("paketfavhover");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
```

For example
When I came on first `<div>` the class `paketfavhover` should be applied to it's child `.paketfav`.

When I came on second `<div>`
ONLY second `.paketfav` addClass ("paketfavhover").

So that in itself  should be changed

Comment: use `$( this ).addClass( "paketfavhover" );`

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP want to add class to the child element `.paketfav` on hover of `.paketler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for that, use CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-class

```
.paketler:hover .paketfav {
    /* Hover styles here */
}
```

```css
.paketler .paketfav {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.paketler:hover .paketfav {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
```

---

If you still want to use jQuery(*not convinced with CSS `:hover`*), you can use jQuery [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1).

```
$(".paketler").hover(function () {
    $(".paketfav", this).addClass("paketfavhover");
}, function () {
    $(".paketfav", this).removeClass("paketfavhover");
});
```

```js
$(".paketler").hover(function() {
  $(".paketfav", this).addClass("paketfavhover");
}, function() {
  $(".paketfav", this).removeClass("paketfavhover");
});
```

```css
.paketfav {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}
.paketfavhover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
<div class="paketler">
  <i class="paketfav"></i>
</div>
```

As an option to context selector, you can also use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$(this).find(".paketfav").addClass("paketfavhover");

$(this).children(".paketfav").addClass("paketfavhover");
```

Comment: Than you very much ! Working